# Can't create table with knexjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to create a table with knexjs however it just doesn't create the table, I tried watching a tutorial and he was creating the table within the migrations file however I really don't like this approach as it doesn't follow MVC, therefore I am wondering how I can make my way work.

It currently doesn't create the table but it doesn't throw an error, I am also wondering if this autogenereates the migrations or what I should do for that, also if this is the correct way of doing it or if I should actually be just writing it all in the migrations file.

Here's my code

```js
class Tasks {
    constructor() {
        try {
            db.schema.createTable('tasks', table => {
                table.increments('id');
                table.string('task', 128)
                    .notNullable();
                table.boolean('completed');
                table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
            });
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query builder with `await`, but that cannot be done in constructor.

So you either need to create a separate async function that runs the table creation or just trigger the query and store promise for

```
class Tasks {
    constructor() {
        try {
          this.initPromise = db.schema.createTable('tasks', table => {
                table.increments('id');
                table.string('task', 128)
                    .notNullable();
                table.boolean('completed');
                table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
            }).then();
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}
```